# AWS RDS on a public subnet

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I have an RDS PostgresSQL running in a VPC, the subnet group used has 2 public and private subnets, and the RDS has the property public accessibility disabled.

my question is what happens when a reboot with failover is performed? the node could take a public subnet?

in that way could it be accessed from the public subnet or is not a big deal having these 2 public subnets in the group because it has disabled the public access property?

Comment: Mixing public and private subnets in a subnet group is not a valid configuration for any reason.  Why do you have this?

Comment: no reason, I just found it on an account, maybe the ones that configured this were not aware, but my doubt is more about if the node it's able to select a public subnet? even having the public accessibility disabled. ??